# How to delete button from a specific cell?

Tags: excel, vba, button

I have a log with several entries. I enter additional data into a row, for example into cell "G3".

If the entered data is a valid date, a button is created in a neighboring cell "J3" of that row:

```vb
Public Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal target As Range)
    Dim intersection As Range
    Dim RgBtn As Range
    Dim Btn As Shape
    Dim wS As Worksheet
    Set intersection = Intersect(target, Columns(7))
    Set wS = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Log")    'Worksheet

    If Not intersection Is Nothing Then

        If IsDate(target.Value) Then
            'MsgBox "Cell " & Target.Address(0, 0) & " contains a valid date."
            'Add Button:
            wS.Unprotect "DoNotChange!"
            Set RgBtn = wS.Range("J" & target.row)
            Set Btn = wS.Shapes.AddFormControl(xlButtonControl, RgBtn.Left, RgBtn.Top, RgBtn.Width, RgBtn.Height)
            With Btn
                .OnAction = "'CreateInvoice " & target.row & "'"
                .OLEFormat.Object.Text = "Create Entry"
            End With
        Else
            'MsgBox "Error..."
        End If

    End If
End Sub
```

When I click that button, data from that range(A3:F3) is copied to another sheet.

I want, after clicking on that button, the button is deleted and replaced by the text "completed".

I tried several approaches to deleting that button.

Comment: In CreateInvoice you can use `Application.Caller` to get a reference to the button/shape so you can delete it

Comment: `Activesheet.Shapes(Application.Caller).Delete`

Comment: So easy!!! Oh man, sometimes...
Thanx a lot Tim, this works like a charm!

Answer (score 0):

You can hide the button.

```
With btn
    .Visible = Not .Visible
End with
```